# Pythonic asyncio communication with unreliable servers

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-3.6, python-asyncio

**Is there a standard pattern for using asyncio to poll intermittent servers?**

Take the following example: a client that reads every second from an unreliable TCP server. Without error handling, the `async/await` notation looks great:

```
class BasicTCPClient(object):
    """TCP client without error handling."""
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port

    async def connect(self):
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.ip, self.port)
        self.connection = {'reader': reader, 'writer': writer}

    async def get(self, request):
        self.connection['writer'].write(request.encode())
        return await self.connection['reader'].readuntil(b'\n')


async def read():
    client = BasicTCPClient('ip', 8000)
    await client.connect()
    while True:
        print(await client.get('request'))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        ioloop.run_until_complete(read())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

But this doesn't handle disconnecting/reconnecting well. I have a working solution, but it's approaching 100 LOC and negates all the elegance of `async/await`.

Comment: QQ: Are you adverse to using the `aiohttp` package for any reason?

Comment: The server doesn't implement HTTP - it's basically serial over TCP. All the examples I've seen for `aiohttp` assume you can get and post.

Comment: Hmm...Ok so aiohttp has a bunch of lower-level (aka socket-level TCP) & pluggable portions to it, but HTTP(s) still seems ref'd in all of the ones I found after a quick look. Once I've got a second to see if some of these objects/methods can be tampered with on the connection-instantiation front, I'll try to post an answer. In the interem, maybe you can do better than I have: 
  - http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/streams.html.  
 &  
  - http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-aiohttp.helpers